# List queues RabbitMQ using Ruby Bunny gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rabbitmq, amqp

Wasn't able to find any documentation on listing the names of the queues and their message counts on the RabbitMQ Bunny docs. I have been able to extract the names and counts using this commandline result if my rabbitmq-server is on the same server as the code

`sudo /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl list_queues`

My rabbitmq server would be running on a different server. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find that the majority of clients that are used for connecting to the RabbitMQ broker are not able to give you this kind of information.

Instead what you want to look at using is the RabbitMQ Management plugin ([see here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api)).

It exposes an HTTP endpoint that you can send GET and POST requests to and receive back information about your queues, connections etc...

To get a list of all the queues in your broker:

Send a GET request to

```
http://therabbitmqhost:15672/api/queues/
```

To get details on a specific queue send a GET request to

```
http://therabbitmqhost:15672/api/queues/thevhost/thequeuename
```

and that will return the message count for that specific queue.

See http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html for details on the API.

Comment: Default http api port is 15672, not 55672, since 3.0